# how to close inapp browser automatically after sharing in facebook

Tags: cordova

i am developing my app in phonegap... i have a news feeds continuously, if user want to share particular post he can...fb page is opening but after sharing it is not going to close...i kept the button top right side like close, but i dont want to stay user in FB..how to route back to app page

my code

```
function fbShare(url,title,descr,image) 
{
    var authorize_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?m2w&s=100&p[title]=' +encodeURI(title) + '&p[summary]=' +encodeURI(descr)+ '&p[url]=' +encodeURI(url)+ '&p[images][0]='+encodeURI(image);
    console.log(authorize_url);
    fb = window.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=yes,closebuttoncaption=close');
    fb.addEventListener('loadstart', fbLoadStart);
    /*fb.addEventListener('loaderror', fbLoaderror);
    fb.addEventListener('exit', fbClose);*/
    /*setTimeout(function() {
        fb.close();
    }, 30000);*/
    /*fb.addEventListener('loadstart', function fbLoadStart(event) { 
        var urlSuccessPage = "https://m.facebook.com/";
        if (event.url == urlSuccessPage) {
        fb.close();    
        }
    });*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this same answer to a 2 days. And I found this link: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/LPT7-rFLsF8

It works perfectly for me:

```
function fLoadStop(event){
    var url = event.url;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    if(filename == "closeInAppBrowser.html"){
         gWindow.close();
     }
}

function fExit(event){
     gWindow.removeEventListener('loadstop', fLoadStop);
     gWindow.removeEventListener('exit', fExit);
}
```

When find some url, trigger close function of the inApp. Good luck! ;)